# Condensing records in a dataframe so the that min and max values of a product's start and end date are kept unless there's a change in status

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have this pandas dataframe:

| Product | Status | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | Good | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31 |
| Apple | Good | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31 |
| Apple | Good | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31 |
| Apple | Good | 2002-01-01 | 2023-09-28 |
| Banana | Bad | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31 |
| Banana | Good | 2002-01-01 | NaT |
| Orange | Good | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31 |
| Orange | Good | 2002-02-01 | NaT |

I'm having trouble writing a code that will do the following:

1. Condense records for products that don't have a status change to only return the min start_date and the max end_date
2. Return a record every time a product switches a status with the min start_date and max end_dates
3. Return a record for every time there's a gap between the first record's end_date and the second record's start_date for a product

Ultimately, based on the example above what I'm looking for is this output:

| Product | Status | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Good | 2000-01-01 | 2023-09-28 |
| Banana | Good | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31 |
| Banana | Bad | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31 |
| Banana | Good | 2002-01-01 | NaT |
| Orange | Good | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31 |
| Orange | Good | 2002-02-01 | NaT |

Any recommendations?

Comment: Why 2023-09-23 for End_Date of Apple product?

Comment: It's the max end_date for Apple. There are no status changes for Apple and the time difference between end_date and start_date records are 1 day. In this instance, I would only want the min start date and max end_date for Apple records

Comment: OK but your input is 2023-09-28 not 2023-09-23.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

make grouper (`grp1`) by changing Product Status & gap of Start Time and previous End Time.

```
cond1 = df.groupby(['Product'])['Status'].shift().ne(df['Status'])
cond2 = df['Start_Date'].sub(df.groupby(['Product'])['End_Date'].shift()).gt(pd.Timedelta('1days'))
grp = (cond1 | cond2).groupby(df['Product']).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(['Product', grp]).agg({'Status':'first', 'Start_Date':'min', 'End_Date':'max'}).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

out:

```
    Product Status  Start_Date  End_Date
0   Apple   Good    2000-01-01  2023-09-28
1   Banana  Good    2000-01-01  2000-12-31
2   Banana  Bad     2001-01-01  2001-12-31
3   Banana  Good    2002-01-01  NaT
4   Orange  Good    2001-01-01  2001-12-31
5   Orange  Good    2002-02-01  NaT
```

---

**Example Codde**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Product': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Orange'], 
         'Status': ['Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good'], 
         'Start_Date': ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', 
                        '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-02-01'], 
         'End_Date': ['2000-12-31', '2000-12-31', '2001-12-31', '2023-09-28', 
                      '2001-12-31', None, '2001-12-31', None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function:

```
def condense(df):
    m2 = df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift())
    m3 = df['Start_Date'] - df['End_Date'].shift() > '1D'
    return (df.groupby((m2|m3).cumsum())
              .agg({'Product': 'first', 'Status': 'first',
                    'Start_Date': 'first', 'End_Date': 'last'}))

out = df.groupby('Product').apply(condense).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Note**: assuming, your dataframe is correctly sorted.

Output:

```
>>> out
  Product Status Start_Date   End_Date
0   Apple   Good 2000-01-01 2023-09-28
1  Banana   Good 2000-01-01 2000-12-31
2  Banana    Bad 2001-01-01 2001-12-31
3  Banana   Good 2002-01-01        NaT
4  Orange   Good 2001-01-01 2001-12-31
5  Orange   Good 2002-02-01        NaT
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work for me (I have a df with more than 100,000 records. The issue is when the same product changes status (good to bad to good). I think I have my df sorted properly... The only thing that I can think of is that the status is sorted ahead of the start_date. I'm guessing that it should be start_date first then status?